# Parse HTML elements from an Iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page with a few iframes in it. The styles of the Iframes are the same but I want to extract/parse html elements from the iframes.

EG: images/header/logo/link

Is there any way to do this with php or JS?

The iframe link is a secure server https so not sure if I can do it or not.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the page in the frame is from the same domain as your page, then you can access its DOM. If not, then you will have to fetch the page on the server-side.

Comment: Are the iframe frames and your originating domain are the same?

Comment: No not on the same domain.

Comment: you can try HTML5 `window.postMessage` to exchange data between iframe and parent Cross-Domain

Comment: Can the author of the iframe blocks parsing ?